# How to Spring Cache JPA nested Objects?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Have Domain Object that has a series of Nested Objects thus. `B` and `C` are reference Data Objects. The values are static data that we never update in the table - ever.

```
Class A {
   B b;
   C c;
}
 
class B {
}

class C {
}
```

B, C etc are quite "heavy" and take some time to return from the DB.

I have a repository written thus:

```
class MyRepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> {
}
```

I need a way to cache `B`, `C` so they are not queried everytime whenever I do this. Currently everytime I lookup `A` both `B` and `C` are retrieved from the DB even though they are static data:

```
MyRepository.findById(1L)
```

I KNOW I can use Spring  Cache at the Service level. But what I'm interested in is DATABASE level Cache. `B`, `C` etc  are using in many different places and more to come (including PUT/POST) so they all can make best use of database level caching of these reference data since using Spring Cache : Save operations dont get much benefits.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if it is what you want.

1. maven add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

2. application.properies add

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

3. entity modify

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache